# InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'ground_truth' with dtype double

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the transfer learning through `Tensorflow`. But I am getting the stated error.
This is my code

```
def add_final_training_ops(graph, class_count, final_tensor_name,
                           ground_truth_tensor_name):
    """Adds a new softmax and fully-connected layer for training.
    We need to retrain the top layer to identify our new classes, so this function
    adds the right operations to the graph, along with some variables to hold the
    weights, and then sets up all the gradients for the backward pass.
    The set up for the softmax and fully-connected layers is based on:
    https://tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html
    Args:
      graph: Container for the existing model's Graph.
      class_count: Integer of how many categories of things we're trying to
      recognize.
      final_tensor_name: Name string for the new final node that produces results.
      ground_truth_tensor_name: Name string of the node we feed ground truth data
      into.
    Returns:
      Nothing.
    """
    bottleneck_tensor1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(ensure_name_has_port(
        BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME))
    bottleneck_tensor = tf.placeholder_with_default(bottleneck_tensor1, shape=[None, 2048])
    layer_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, class_count], stddev=0.001),
        name='final_weights')
    layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
    logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_tensor, layer_weights,
                       name='final_matmul') + layer_biases
    tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
    ground_truth_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,
                                              [None, class_count],
                                              name=ground_truth_tensor_name)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=ground_truth_placeholder)
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(
        cross_entropy_mean)
    return train_step, cross_entropy_mean

def do_train(sess,X_input, Y_input, X_validation, Y_validation):
    ground_truth_tensor_name = 'ground_truth'
    mini_batch_size = 10
    n_train = X_input.shape[0]

    graph = create_graph()

    train_step, cross_entropy = add_final_training_ops(
        graph, len(classes), FLAGS.final_tensor_name,
        ground_truth_tensor_name)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    evaluation_step = add_evaluation_step(graph, FLAGS.final_tensor_name, ground_truth_tensor_name)

    # Get some layers we'll need to access during training.
    bottleneck_tensor1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(ensure_name_has_port(BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME))
    bottleneck_tensor = tf.placeholder_with_default(bottleneck_tensor1, shape=[None, 2048])
    ground_truth_tensor1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(ensure_name_has_port(ground_truth_tensor_name))
    ground_truth_tensor = tf.placeholder_with_default(ground_truth_tensor1, shape=[None, len(classes)])

    i=0
    epocs = 1
    for epoch in range(epocs):
        shuffledRange = np.random.permutation(n_train)
        y_one_hot_train = encode_one_hot(len(classes), Y_input)
        y_one_hot_validation = encode_one_hot(len(classes), Y_validation)
        shuffledX = X_input[shuffledRange,:]
        shuffledY = y_one_hot_train[shuffledRange]
        for Xi, Yi in iterate_mini_batches(shuffledX, shuffledY, mini_batch_size):
            print Xi.shape
            print type(Xi)
            print type(Yi)
            print Yi.shape
            print Yi.dtype
            print Yi[0]
            sess.run(train_step,
                     feed_dict={bottleneck_tensor: Xi,
                                ground_truth_tensor: Yi})
```

Print statements has the following outputs :

```
(10, 2048)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(10, 5)
float64
[ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
```

I am getting the error at :

```
sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={bottleneck_tensor: Xi,ground_truth_tensor: Yi})
```

Can someone tell me why I am facing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you created a placeholder in `add_final_training_ops` that you don't feed. You might think that the placeholder `ground_truth_tensor` that you create in `add_final_training_ops` is the same, but it is not, it is a new one, even if it is initialized by the former.

The easiest fix would be perhaps to return the placeholder from `add_final_training_ops` and use this one instead.

Comment: Then how bottleneck_tensor is initialised?